# Oracle equivalent to SQL Server STUFF function?

Tags: oracle, select

Does Oracle have its own implementation of SQL Server `stuff` function?

Stuff allows you to receive one value from a multi row select. Consider my situation below

```
 ID   HOUSE_REF   PERSON
 1      A         Dave
 2      A         John
 3      B         Bob
```

I would like to write a select statement, but I want the `PERSON` names to be in a single row.

For example, when I select from this table, I want to achieve the following

```
HOUSE_REF   PERSONS
A           Dave, John
B           Bob
```

I haven't been able to find a simple solution so far, it may be a case of writing my own function to use, but I'm not entirely sure of how to approach this, any ideas?

The main business use of this, will be to have a select statement that shows each house, and against that house to have one column which lists everyone that lives in that house. The house ref in this select must be unique, hence needing to concatenate the persons

Thanks

Comment: You have misunderstood what T-SQL `STUFF` does. See the documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx. It could be used as part of a solution for what you're trying to do, but isn't the solution in itself.

Comment: Not Oracle related - but MySQL has a function called GROUP_CONCAT that appears to solve the problem described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom aggregate function to do this. This string you generate is limited to 4k characters.

http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-11591.html

There is an undocumented, unsupported function `WMSYS.WM_CONCAT` to do the same thing.

http://www.psoug.org/reference/undocumented.html

Comment: Oracle 11gR2 has a listagg() function: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions089.htm#CJABDFBD

Answer (score 9):

Oracle 11.2 includes a new function [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm#insertedID0) to do this.

Prior to that you could use [Tom Kyte's STRAGG function](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:250238800346872505).

Comment: Using LISTAGG is really the most appropriate and easy way! The documentation link has changed: [LISTAGG - doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm#SQLRF55593)

Comment: Updated documentation link. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030

Answer (score 3):

The "no add-ons/no undocumented functions" Oracle solution (prior to 11.2 as Tony mentions) is:

```
select c1, ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(c2,','),',') persons
 from
  (
   select c1, c2, 
    row_number() over (partition by c1 order by c2 ) rn
     from
      (
       select house_ref c1, person c2 
        from housetable 
      )
   )
  where connect_by_isleaf=1
  connect by prior rn+1 =rn and prior c1 = c1
  start with rn=1
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Execute below three functions.

**Function 1**

> create or replace type stragg_type as
>   object (   string varchar2(4000),
>
> static function
>   ODCIAggregateInitialize
>       ( sctx in out stragg_type )
>       return number ,
>
> member function ODCIAggregateIterate
>       ( self  in out stragg_type ,
>         value in     varchar2
>       ) return number ,
>
> member function
>   ODCIAggregateTerminate
>       ( self        in  stragg_type,
>         returnvalue out varchar2,
>         flags in number
>       ) return number ,
>
> member function ODCIAggregateMerge
>       ( self in out stragg_type,
>         ctx2 in     stragg_type
>       ) return number );

/

**function 2**

> create or replace type body
>   stragg_type is
>
> static function
>   ODCIAggregateInitialize   ( sctx in
>   out stragg_type )   return number   is
>   begin
>
> ```
> sctx := stragg_type( null ) ;
>
> return ODCIConst.Success ;
> ```
>
> end;
>
> member function ODCIAggregateIterate
>   ( self  in out stragg_type ,
>       value in     varchar2   ) return number   is   begin
>
> ```
> self.string := self.string || ',' || value ;
>
> return ODCIConst.Success;
> ```
>
> end;
>
> member function
>   ODCIAggregateTerminate   ( self
>   in  stragg_type ,
>       returnvalue out varchar2 ,
>       flags       in  number   ) return number   is   begin
>
> ```
> returnValue := ltrim( self.string, ',' );
>
> return ODCIConst.Success;
> ```
>
> end;
>
> member function ODCIAggregateMerge
>   ( self in out stragg_type ,
>       ctx2 in     stragg_type   ) return number   is   begin
>
> ```
> self.string := self.string || ctx2.string;
>
> return ODCIConst.Success;
> ```
>
> end;
>
> end; /

**function 3**

> create or replace function stragg   (
>   input varchar2 )   return varchar2
>   deterministic   parallel_enable
>   aggregate using stragg_type ; /

---

### after executing three functions now u can use stragg as follows

> Example Table :emp name | salary a
>   | 100 a    | 200 a    | 300 b    | 400
>   b    | 500 c    | 600 c    | 700 d
>   | 800
>
> select  name ,  STRAGG( salary) as
>   string from  emp group by name;

**output:**

> a   | 100,200,300
>
> b   |  400,500
>
> c   |  600,700
>
> d   |  800

Comment: Should give credit for this answer where it is due: http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-11591.html