# Is there a stuff() function available in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Is there any equivalent stuff function in oracle? I used the stuff function in mssql to convert the raw datetime ( in string format) to proper datetime 
MSSQL Query

```
select convert(datetime,
      '20'+substring(stuff(stuff(stuff(stuff(stuff(stuff(convert(varchar,'24051103084950') , 3,0,'-'), 6,0,'-'), 9,0,' '), 12,0,':'), 15,0,':'), 17,2,''),7,2)+'-' 
      +SUBSTRING(stuff(stuff(stuff(stuff(stuff(stuff(convert(varchar,'24051103084950'),3,0,'-'),   6,0,'-'),  9,0,' '), 12,0,':'), 15,0,':'), 17,2,''),4,2)+'-'
      +SUBSTRING (stuff(stuff(stuff(stuff(stuff(stuff(convert(varchar,'24051103084950'), 3,0,'-'), 6,0,'-'), 9,0,' '), 12,0,':'), 15,0,':'), 17,2,''),1,2)
      + SUBSTRING(stuff(stuff(stuff(stuff(stuff(stuff( convert(varchar,'24051103084950'),3,0,'-'),   6,0,'-'), 9,0,' '), 12,0,':'), 15,0,':'), 17,2,''),9,15))
```

In the above query **'24051103084950'** is the raw data which is in **ddmmyyhhmiss** format. The output for the above query is as follows

```
(No column name)
2011-05-24 03:08:40.000
```

I need to convert the same query into oracle. Guide me to do it.

Comment: have you tried to google your title ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108194/oracle-equivalent-to-sql-server-stuff-function

Comment: yep i tried, It returns some userdefined functions, not a query or a equivalent predefined function :-(

Comment: Have you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2108872/284240

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the timestamp/string conversion functions to simplify this:

```
select to_char(
         to_timestamp('24051103084950', 'DDMMYYHH24MISSFF2'), 
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') 
  from dual
```

N.B. FF2 is milliseconds to 2 places, FF3 is milliseconds to 3 places.