# ORA-01427 - Subquery returns more than one record

Tags: sql, oracle

Im generating a scaffold view in Oracle for other work i need. I'm just getting my feet wet in Oracle and SQL in general.

I want to get this:

```
DATE_       I           II          III
13-DEC-16   CATEGORY    SUBCATEGORY SITE_NAME_A
13-DEC-16   CATEGORY    SUBCATEGORY SITE_NAME_B
13-DEC-16   CATEGORY    SUBCATEGORY SITE_NAME_C
14-DEC-16   CATEGORY    SUBCATEGORY SITE_NAME_A
14-DEC-16   CATEGORY    SUBCATEGORY SITE_NAME_B
14-DEC-16   CATEGORY    SUBCATEGORY SITE_NAME_C
...
```

From this:

```
   SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE - (3) + (LEVEL)) AS DATE_,
          'CATEGORY' AS I,
          'SUBCATEGORY' AS II,                  
          (SELECT UNIQUE VENDOR_SITE_CODE FROM AP_INVOICES_V WHERE VENDOR_NAME = 'SOMETHING') AS III
     FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SYSDATE - (SYSDATE - (3)))
```

This of course works if the sub-query returns a single record, but throws the "too many records" error when not.How can i work around this? I do want to get the extra records because they are new site names but dont know how to plug them in the view.

Thanks!

Edit: for clarification, the vendor may have more than one vendor_site, that's when the too many records error merges.
Also noted the output example was wrong, corrected it.

Comment: Before this gets flagged as a duplicate tyake a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108194/oracle-equivalent-to-sql-server-stuff-function?

Comment: I feel that you need join, but I do not understand what exactly you are trying to accomplish. For example how do you want to tie site name to date ? Why site_name_a is at 13-dec-16 and not 14-dec-16 ? Is there any rule ?

Comment: `How can i work around this?` - id depends on how do you want to present these additional records on your report. This error simply means, that there are more than 1 sites with `VENDOR_NAME = 'SOMETHING'`. Do you want to show them all ? Or pick only one random site ?

Comment: thank you for your replies guys, please check my edited note.

Comment: Your Edit still doesn't answer the key question: When there is more than one location, what should be shown in the output? Options: More than one row (it can be done in the OUTPUT, perhaps not with your query, but you don't seem to want it); a random location, or perhaps the most recently added one, etc.; a comma-separated list of all locations, in alphabetical order or in the order they were added, etc. There are so many possibilities. Which one is closest to what you need?

Comment: @mathguy for every site_name should be a new row.

Answer (score 0):

probably you looking for [ListAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) for that one `(SELECT UNIQUE VENDOR_SITE_CODE FROM AP_INVOICES_V WHERE VENDOR_NAME = 'SOMETHING') AS III`

Comment: I'd like to do actually the inverse of ListAgg.

Answer (score 0):

If you need new site names as additional rows, then
instead of making it a subquery, join it with main table and use distinct to avoid duplicate records. Add or remove WHERE clause depending on your need

```
SELECT distinct TRUNC (SYSDATE - (3) + (LEVEL)) AS DATE_,
              'CATEGORY' AS I,
              'SUBCATEGORY' AS II,                  
              VENDOR_SITE_CODE  AS III,
              VENDOR_NAME,
              LEVEL
         FROM DUAL,AP_INVOICES_V WHERE VENDOR_NAME = 'SOMETHING'
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SYSDATE - (SYSDATE - (3)))
```

If you want to add new site names in existing rows then use Oracle analytical function LISTAGG with partition by VENDOR_NAME

```
SELECT  TRUNC (SYSDATE - (3) + (LEVEL)) AS DATE_,
          'CATEGORY' AS I,
          'SUBCATEGORY' AS II,                 
         ( SELECT DISTINCT LISTAGG(VENDOR_SITE_CODE,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY VENDOR_SITE_CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY VENDOR_NAME) FROM AP_INVOICES_V WHERE VENDOR_NAME='VENDOR1') AS III
     FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SYSDATE - (SYSDATE - (3)))
```

Comment: Thank you Vija, but this takes forever, cant even test it.

Comment: @GabrielA.Zorrilla Which query you are trying and how many rows does your table has?